# Error: Failed to launch the browser process! (NodeJs - Cpannel) (libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cpanel

When I made my web scraping tool, it ***works perfectly on my computer***. But when I upload it to my host ***sluhosting*** -> then onto ***CPANEL*** -> and I make a ***nodejs application***. When I try it then I get this ***error*** when I try to run it.

Im using puppeteer version: ***"puppeteer": "^7.0.4"*** and nodejs version: ***v10.22.0***

````
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/MY-USER-NAME-HERE/nodevenv/server/10/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-843427/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/MY-USER-NAME-HERE/nodevenv/server/10/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
    at Interface.helper_js_1.helper.addEventListener (/home/MY-USER-NAME-HERE/nodevenv/server/10/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:183:68)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:397:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:173:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)```
````

Comment: Read the error message, it says you're missing some shared libraries on that system `error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I know but what do i need to do to fix it that's the thing I can't figger out.

Comment: I don't know how that sluhosting works, but you need to install the library, e.g. in Ubuntu via `$ apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-0` https://gist.github.com/winuxue/cfef08e2f5fe9dfc16a1d67a4ad38a01 There might be issues with permissions, so you might need to run puppeteer inside a container where you can install anything.

Comment: i don't  have access to ssh or a terminal on cpannel is it still possible ?

Comment: Can i install it on my local computer and then it works on cpannel ? or I don't get it

Comment: You need to install it on a machine where your tests run. If you install it locally, where you must have it if the tests work, it's of no use on the sluhosting server.

Comment: So i need to run this on my host cpanel oke

Comment: Or can i use ssh to install it ?

Comment: @StanPersoons did you solve this? I am facing the same issue. Please let me know how you solved it.

Comment: @s.khan Sorry for the late reaction, it turned out that it is not possible to use a driver of any kind of browser on shared hosting servers. If your on a VPS that you own then it is possible by just installing the packages you need.

Comment: @StanPersoons Thanks so much for the info. Sadly I'm using a shared hosting. I guess it's time I take a VPS. Thanks brother./